# How to use scipy.integrate.dblquad when function is defined on a mesh?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to calculate the scipy double integral of the function called `func` below. The example given here is mathematically an over-simplification of my actual project, however the structure of the objects are the same. In essence, `list1` acts as coordinates in the x-direction, and `list2` the same in the y-direction, and so `ffunc` evaluated at x=2 and y=3, for example, would be `ffunc[2,3]`.

In the following code, I'm getting `IndexError: only integers, slices (:), ellipsis (...), numpy.newaxis (None) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices` and I don't understand how to proceed.

Note that the lambda definition seems solid, printing `func(2,3)` for example, returns the expected numerical float of 5.0.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy

num = int(5)
list1=np.linspace(0,1,num)
list2=np.linspace(0,1,num)
ffunc=np.zeros((num,num))

for a in range(num):
    for b in range(num):
        ffunc[a,b] = a+b

func = lambda x,y: ffunc[x,y]
temp = scipy.integrate.dblquad(func,min(list2),max(list2),min(list1),max(list1))
print(temp)
```